# Calling a plugin .on() load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling some jQuery plugins that attaches themselves to element on DOM ready. These plugins manipulate the DOM when certain events has occurred (click, change etc,)

```
$("body").find("input[type='checkbox']").checkbox();
```

Above works fine on DOM ready. However, if I'm loading some HTML from an AJAX call I have to use `.on()` to guarantee events gets bound consistently.

The question is which event I should bind the plugin to? I have tried below and it doesn't seem to respond.

```
  $("body").on("load", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){
            $(this).checkbox();
  });
```

Here's the checkbox() plugin I'm referring to above. If that's any help. :)

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery'], function($){

    return function(){

        $.fn.checkbox = function (options) {
            options = options || {};

            var defaults = {
                'className': 'jquery-checkbox',
                'checkedClass': 'jquery-checkbox-on'
            };

            var settings = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var self = jQuery(this);

                var replacement = jQuery(
                    '<span class="' + settings.className + '-wrapper">' +
                    '<a class="' + settings.className + '" href="#" name="' + self.attr('id') + '"></a>' +
                    '</span>');
                var element = jQuery('a', replacement);

                if (self.prop('checked')) {
                    element.addClass(settings.checkedClass);
                }

                element.on('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    var input = jQuery('input#' + jQuery(this).attr('name'), replacement.parent());
                    if (input.prop('checked')) {
                        input.removeAttr('checked');
                    } else {
                        input.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    input.trigger('change');

                    return false;
                });

                element.on('focusin', function (event) {
                    $(this).addClass('checkbox-focus');
                });

                element.on('focusout', function (event) {
                    $(this).removeClass('checkbox-focus');
                });

                element.on("keypress", function(e){
                    if ( e.which === 32 ){ self.prop('checked', !self.prop('checked')).change(); }
                });

                self.on('change', function (event) {
                    var input = jQuery(this);
                    if (input.prop('checked')) {
                        jQuery('a[name=' + input.attr('id') + ']', replacement.parent()).addClass(settings.checkedClass);
                    } else {
                        jQuery('a[name=' + input.attr('id') + ']', replacement.parent()).removeClass(settings.checkedClass);
                    }
                    return true;
                });

                self.css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': '-200px',
                    'left': '-10000px'
                }).before(replacement);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you try the event you actually want, like `click` etc.

Comment: Are you trying to bind to elements loaded by the Ajax? If so use `document` for `on` bindings and never `body` (`body` seems to have some "quirks") and specify the actual events you want from those controls like "click" :)

Comment: The plugin actually listens to events rather than trigger on event..If that makes sense!

Comment: So then what are you trying to do? Trigger a special event or what? If you just want to attach the plugin after the elements are loaded you'd do that in the callback for your ajax call ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry for being ambiguous. I have added the plugin code above. Yes I know I can call the plugin in the callback was trying avoid that as If I have multiple places where I require above plugin to be loaded I will need to always call the plugin in all the callbacks. Thanks

Comment: You *must* call it in the load callbacks... Delegated events do not do what you think. You cannot delegate `load` as that would apply once only to the page (if it worked at all).

Comment: I agree, I have being using similar add-ins where they've being called by an event like "click" with .on() successfully. I was wondering if there's a similar way to bind add-ins on load regardless of the way content has being loaded (via Ajax or not).

Comment: Not really, there are mutation observers, but you really shouldn't go down that route

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to apply add-ins to elements that have been loaded dynamically. That is not what 'on' is for.

*Delegated events* listen for *specific* events (like "click") at a parent/ancestor element then filter the possible recipients, then executes the supplied function against any matching elements that caused the event.

**You actually need to apply the add-in code after your Ajax load completes.**

### Example:

In the success part of your ajax load, apply the addin:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkbox();
```

If you loaded a specific part of the screen (likely), then target the selector at that element:

e.g.

```
$("#myloadcontainer input[type='checkbox']").checkbox();
```